# How to reload URL using phonegap on android?

Tags: android, cordova

In the onCreate() method, is there a way to reload URL? I am trying to reload URL every minute

```
public class AAPActivity extends DroidGap
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {           
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        task = new TimerTask(){
                                public void run() {
                                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                            public void run() {

                                               // Here instead of loadURL, is there a way to reload?          
                                               loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
                                            }
                                   });
                            }};

       t.schedule(task, 0, 10000); 
    } 
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is a Phonegap App you will probably use javascript. I found this:

```
<script type = "text/Javascript">

function refresh() {
window.location.reload(true);
tim = setTimeout("refresh()",60000); // refresh every minute
}

</script>
```

on http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-157966.html . Maybe that helps ;)

Comment: setInterval would probably be better